# Is it possible to replace app in google play console with different programming language used?

Tags: android, web, flutter, google-play, hybrid-mobile-app

Is it possible to replace the released app(apk) in google play console?
The app is already downloadable in the google play. 
However, the released app is a Hybrid App(Web-Based) and 
the plan is that the app will be migrated to Flutter.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yeah it is possible you just need to use the same package name and key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue: wrote an app in Java and then translated it into Kotlin. I just uploaded new apk as an update/new version of the app, and it worked!